# Using PHP mail() in a loop

Tags: php, email

This is regarding mass e-mail sending with PHP. I have to send around 10000 emails and I am using PHP mail() function inside a loop. My server sends 500 mails per hour. I would like to know what will happen to the e-mails after 500.

Comment: "I would like to know what will happen to the mails after 500" --- you would better don't know that.

Comment: when you say "My server sends 500 mails per hr", are you referring to a server-set limit? Generally the server will queue up messages if they're being generated faster than they can be sent... the queue will then send out as resources become available. The queue itself may also have a separate cap, which will cause new messages requests to be ignored.

Comment: @Dr.Dan My first thought as well. How about sending out a newsletter to 10.000 of your customers that have requested to get the newsletter ?

Comment: @barts if he has 10000 customers, and considering OP to be programmer of that site, he wouldn't have asked this trivial question.

Comment: @itachi jumping to conclusions as well. Why can't he be a PHP novice who's helping out someone? Maybe he does not even use a site (at least he did not mention anything about it)... bla bla bla

Comment: @barts: more than 10000 emails within 1 hour.... this isn't a tiny site. if someone made it, he will atleast know the work around. So who left? a novice php programmer who wants to spam. (99.99%)

Comment: @itachi 10000 emails in 1 hour.. not 'every' hour if that is done once a month or year, I don't think it's a lot. so I like to reduce your % to 50-50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to ask your host.

Your host probably has some intervening script such as milter-limit (http://www.milter.info/sendmail/milter-limit/) which has a range of options: including reject (you'll probably get a message back), discard (no message) or later (temporary rejection).

I doubt a shared host would queue for later. This limit is really designed to stop spammers who may hack your account - why would they queue spammer's emails in some automated system - they would want to intervene and delete the junk to save the reputation of the server? So I would guess "reject" or "discard".

Alternatively, they may not have any system at all and monitor the mail queue - if it gets too long then they investigate, find the culprit and delete all their e-mails (and the account if a repeat offended / a new acccount). That's what my host does.

But there's only at's a guess - check with your host.

I wouldn't risk it in case they don't have something automated and they do fall back on the "delete account" option.

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving some "sleep timings" after sending few mails and sent remaining in the same manner....

Answer (score 0):

Your server sends 500 mails per hour usually means that your host let's you send only 500 mails in a 1 hour interval.

That's why you should use a cronjob that sends 500 mails than stops, and after one hour sends 500 more mails until there are no mails to be sent.

In reply to your question this is an official answer from a web hosting company:

*While trying to send mail, if you receive an error message which says "Policy Rejection- Quota Exceeded" that means that you have exceeded, or attempted to exceed your mail sending limit for that particular account. Also, if you attempt to send messages and do not use the correct FROM address the system will also give you this error and will not send your message.*